# "Suddenly" am getting an Invalid Subclass Error when calling YAML.load_file

Tags: ruby, yaml, rspec2

I'm using:
Rails 3.0.7 and 
Rspec 2.5.0
via rvm

When I run this spec (using autotest or bundle exec autotest or bundle exec rspec spec/) below:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'yaml'

def twitter_feed(id=1) 
   ruby_object = YAML.load_file(::Rails.root.to_s + "/spec/fixtures/feeds/twitter_response_#{id}.yml")
end
```

I get this:

```
 Failure/Error: ruby_object = YAML.load_file(::Rails.root.to_s + "/spec/fixtures/feeds/twitter_response_#{id}.yml")
    TypeError:
      invalid subclass
      # ./spec/models/tweet_spec.rb:6:in `twitter_feed'
      # /Users/natebean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `transfer'
      # /Users/natebean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `node_import'
      # /Users/natebean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
      # /Users/natebean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
      # /Users/natebean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:144:in `load_file'
      # /Users/natebean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:143:in `open'
      # /Users/natebean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:143:in `load_file'
      # ./spec/models/tweet_spec.rb:5:in `twitter_feed'
      # ./spec/models/tweet_spec.rb:58
```

This "was" working.  I can't find any other information on this error on the internet.  I've moved from rails 3.0.3 to 3.0.7, but don't remember it not working after the upgrade.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: What's the YAML file look like? I expect you serialized an object, maybe instance of a model, which inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, but in your spec where you deserialize it, it doesn't know about ActiveRecord or your model (maybe require the models)

Comment: I hope it's not another Syck versus Psych issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yaml file I was pulling was looking for Hashie::Mash to map the data to.  Up to know I didn't need to require 'hashie', but that has "fixed this problem".

I added to this to my spec and it is now working.

```
require 'hashie'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle exec rspec spec --backtrace` to get a full backtrace so you can see exactly where that error is coming from.